# Unidentified items in bicycle tube repair kit

Tags: repair

What are these items in my bicycle tube repair kit for? I found them in several repair kits but I do not know what to use them for?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen these things. Which kit they are from?

Comment: Were there instructions in the kit? Can you search the kit's brand name or model name on youtube and find a video of how the kit is used? I think a lot of people are confused by the premise of your question since the fact that these are patches is somewhat self explanatory based on the fact that they're in a repair kit. To make a reference to your avatar, your question reads like someone saying, " I bought a box of cookies and found these inside, what are they for?" accompanied by a photo of a cookie.

Comment: These look very much unlike any tube patch I have seen. I also wonder how they are used since they lack two essential qualities of a patch: (a) they do not get thinner towards the rim; (b) there is no clear plastic wrap on the outer side, it is needed to rub on the patch to ensure the pressure in the contact area is high enough for bonds to form. They also don't have the orange looking butyl rubber along their edges.

Comment: This may be country specific or something but every single patch I have seen before has been roundish shape on tin foil backing paper, never anything like this.

Comment: What country/area are you from?

Comment: @ojs I've seen them on metal foil or plastic film but, yeah, nothing like the ones in the photo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be used to temporarily repair a tyre. If you (for example) go over a stone which tears a hole in your tyre as well as your inner tube. Simply fixing the inner tube will leave it exposed so it will puncture again. Place this tyre patch in between the inner tube and the type hole. Hopefully it will last long enough to get you home...

Comment: You would use the canvas in the kit to temporary repair the tyre, these are for the tube.

Answer (score 12):

They are tube patches. Here’s the contents of one of my kits: 
[image]

From top to bottom, we have,

- plastic container
- tyre levers to remove the tyre
- crayon to mark the location of the puncture on the tube
- sandpaper to roughen the tube surface prior to ‘gluing’
- rubber solution to attach the patch
- tube patches with a black front and a white backing. Remove one patch from the sheet then peel off its backing before you apply.
- chalk to sprinkle over the finished patch to prevent sticking to the tyre after reinstalling

Now you know what they are you can get instructions online or in my case on the back of the tube of rubber solution

Answer (score 8):

Those are blocks of various sized rubber tube patches stamped from a single larger sheet of rubber. Individual patches are torn off the block as needed.

Patches are applied over holes in the inner tube, bonded to it with de-vulcanizing solution, which causes the polymers in the rubber patch and tube to join to one another.

Answer (score 0):

These are patches for inner tubes found inside the tires. Some tires are tubeless and required different patch kits.